# Spigot/Bukkit - Play own sound/music - Java

Tags: java, audio, bukkit

how can I play a custom sound/music for a specified Player or in a specified region? I know how to play a minecraft Sound (`Player.playSound(Player.getLocation(), Sound.*sound*, 1.0f, 1.0f`), but is there a way to play a Sound/music from a .ogg File?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minecraft servers can't stream music to clients. Your only solution is to use note blocks and midi files

Comment: But how is for example Wynncraft doing it? Also via note blocks?

Comment: @Nightfighter001 probably yes. A lot of servers do that. They may edit notes with resourcepack (to make them sound differently), but i think that's it. You can actually change noteblocks volume and music will go off

Comment: Okay than Thank You! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can in fact play custom music and sounds to players, however it requires the use of a resource pack on the client side.

The resource pack needs to contain the sound file (I'm not sure what formats are supported), the sounds.json file needs to be updated with the location of your sound.

From there, you just need to play the sound, which works like you would any other Minecraft sound. For the sound value/path, just put what you entered into the sounds.json file

More information about resource packs can be found here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Resource_pack

Comment: Well thank you, but my question was if it is possible to play a soundfile without doing something with the client...

Answer (score 2):

You can play sound using the method: world.playEffect

However if the sound doesn't already exist for the client you can't do that, Also you can only call sounds that are specified in the Sound enum, The only way to play custom sounds (That don't already exist in minecraft) is to let the client download a recourcepack containing the custom sound.